# C++ Passing Pointer To A Function

Tags: c++

I have a problem passing a pointer to a function. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int age = 14;
int weight = 66;

int SetAge(int &rAge);
int SetWeight(int *pWeight);

int main()
{
    int &rAge = age;
    int *pWeight = &weight;

    cout << "I am " << rAge << " years old." << endl;   
    cout << "And I am " << *pWeight << " kg." << endl;

    cout << "Next year I will be " << SetAge(rAge) << " years old." << endl;
    cout << "And after a big meal I will be " << SetWeight(*pWeight);
    cout << " kg." << endl;
    return 0;
}

int SetAge(int &rAge) 
{
    rAge++;
    return rAge;
}

int SetWeight(int *pWeight)
{
    *pWeight++;
    return *pWeight;
}
```

My compiler outputs this:

```
|| C:\Users\Ivan\Desktop\Exercise01.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Exercise01.cpp|20 col 65 error| invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
||   cout << "And after a big meal I will be " << SetWeight(*pWeight);
||                                                                  ^
Exercise01.cpp|9 col 5 error| initializing argument 1 of 'int SetWeight(int*)'    [-fpermissive]
||  int SetWeight(int *pWeight);
||      ^
```

PS: In real life I wouldnt use this but I got into it and I wanna get it working this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't dereference the pointer. It should be:

```
cout << "And after a big meal I will be " << SetWeight(pWeight);
```

Also, in `SetWeight()`, you are incrementing the pointer instead of incrementing the value, it should be:

```
int SetWeight(int *pWeight)
{
    (*pWeight)++;
    return *pWeight;
}
```

Comment: Did it but my output is ""After a big meal I will be -1 kg"

Comment: Fixed it. I needed to change *pWeight++; to *pWeight += 1; and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *pWeight = &weight;
```

This declares `pWeight` as a pointer to an `int`. `SetWeight` actually takes a pointer to an `int`, so you can just pass `pWeight` straight in without any other qualifiers:

```
cout << "And after a big meal I will be " << SetWeight(pWeight);
```

Comment: Did it but my output is ""After a big meal I will be -1 kg"

Comment: Fixed it. I needed to change *pWeight++; to *pWeight += 1; and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First I took your feedback and changed:

```
cout << "And after a big meal I will be " << SetWeight(*pWeight);
// to
cout << "And after a big meal I will be " << SetWeight(pWeight);

// But after that I changed also:
*pWeight++;
// to
*pWeight += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The * symbol can have two different meanings in C++. When used in a function header, they indicate that the variable being passed is a pointer. When used elsewhere in front of a pointer it indicates that to which the pointer is pointing. It seems you may have confused these.